# Leveraging secure credentials to run an executable in a powershell script

Tags: powershell

I am trying to replace a batch file that runs an automated upload process with a PowerShell script that provides better security.  Currently, the executable in the batch file is run with credentials that are displayed in clear text as part of a switch.  I am new to PowerShell and am having difficulty understanding how to call these credentials and apply them to the executable file I am trying to run.  There seem to be a lot of posts about applying saved credentials to cmdlets, but little about working with executables. Below is a copy of my current script.

```
$credPath = 'D:\Temp\axupload.txt'
$fileCred = Import-CliXml -Path $credPath
& 'D:\Program Files (x86)\XtenderSolutions\Content Management\IndexImageImport.exe' -Credential $fileCred --% /A HR_PERSONNEL_OPTION1 /S "HR_PERSONNEL" /F "\\imageserver1\aximport\HR\Weekly_Upload\WCHR10B.AppXtender.20180928.txt" /Q
```

The error message I receive is below.  It specifically relates to passing through the `/u userid` and `/w password` switches to the executable.  I am trying to do this by calling the credential file I have already created and saved, but this is not working so there must be a different way to accomplish this.  Maybe, as an argument?

[image: Application error message]

Below is the key command line from the batch file.  I have redacted the username and password with XXXX's.
"D:\Program Files (x86)\XtenderSolutions\Content Management\IndexImageImport.exe" /U XXXX /W XXXXXXXXXXXX /A HR_PERSONNEL_OPTION1 /S "HR_PERSONNEL" /F "\imageserver1\aximport\hr\WCHR10A.AppXtender.Updated.TXT"

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks,

Comment: `-Credential` is only going to work if you exe automatically uses the credentials of the running user. Guessing it does not. Are you able to start cmd as the user and run the exe without the  /u and /p? Else I think you need to get the unencrypted password string from your credential object

Comment: Can you edit your post and show parts of the bat script. Mainly this part in the BAT
'D:\Program Files (x86)\XtenderSolutions\Content Management\IndexImageImport.exe' -Credential $fileCred --% /A HR_PERSONNEL_OPTION1 /S "HR_PERSONNEL" /F "\\imageserver1\aximport\HR\Weekly_Upload\WCHR10B.AppXtender.20180928.txt" /Q

Comment: I am thinking you are right about the password string.  Would that be applied as some type of $args?  Not sure how to structure that with exe.  Maybe, eliminate the -credential altogether and add all the switches as arguments?

Comment: Honestly this is possible and not possible same time. You can encrypt the password and decrypt in when its used but then you need to worry about a AES key. and anyone that gets the Key, username, password can still decrypt it. You can also do it by windows encryption which will encrypt it using the current user as reference. But then only that user is able to decrypt the password and run the executable.
It really comes down to what your situation is. I guess the question is ...is this script only run under a single user on a single machine?

Comment: This particular script will only be run on one server by one user, which will be a service account.  So no need to run it anywhere else.